# How to use layout_below in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, xml, layout, view

Here is my code(not all code,i have deleted some):

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/info_in_my"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/head_in_my"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_size_36dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pic_in_my"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_size_36dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/icon_policeman" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_in_my"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AAAAAA"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/pic_in_my"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="@color/font_white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/organization_in_my"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name_in_my"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/pic_in_my"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/font_white" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**This is the result:**

[image]

I want String `BBBBBBBBB` is below String `AAAAAA`, so it's not right.

And i deleted `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` in the first `TextView` but no changes.

Is  `android:layout_below="@+id/name_in_my"` useless when First `View` uses `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

I want to know why?

Comment: I add            ' android:layout_marginTop="55dp"' it works well

Comment: If you are doing that in your toolbar, you better check appbarlayout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, "How to use layout_below in RelativeLayout?", check this example:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/b1"
    .... />
<Button android:id="@+id/b2"
    android:layout_below="@id/b1"
    .... />
```

This means that you want button `b2` to be below `b1`. Note that I used `@id` instead of `@+id` because I already added the id `b1` in my declaration of button `b1`, thus, there is no reason to add it again.

Since you want `BBBBB` below `AAAA`, you have to put `layout_below="id of AAAA"` in `BBBB`.

`android:layout_centerInParent` means that you want the view to be at the center of the parent, which in your case is the whole relative layout.

Comment: Relativelayout attribute names are ridiculously confusing. It's been years and I still get confused when I need to align something on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

try below layout -

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:id="@+id/info_in_my"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/head_in_my"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_size_36dp"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pic_in_my"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_size_36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pic_in_my"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/pic_in_my"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pic_in_my">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_in_my"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AAAAAA"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@color/font_white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_18sp"
        />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_12sp"
    android:textColor="@color/font_white"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name_in_my"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name_in_my"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/name_in_my" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Remove this line ``android:layout_toEndOf="@id/pic_in_my"`` in ``name_in_my TextView`` , you can't do this without ``info_in_my RelativeLayout``

Answer (score 0):

Use `toRightOf` instead of `toEndOf` in `textviews`